# How FindInstance can find all the solutions over a given range of parameters

Tags: equation-solving, findinstance

```
sol3 = {h2, h1, d, t, b, c} /.FindInstance[(h2^2 ((1 + d*Sin[t]^2)))/(16 \[Pi]^2) b == 1.14 && (h1*h2 (d (Sin[2 t])))/(2*16 \[Pi]^2) c == 0.1 && 
10^4 < b < 10^6 && 10^4 < c < 10^6 && 0 <= d <= 1 && 0 <= t <= \[Pi]/2 && 0.01 < h2 < 1 && 0.1 < h1 < 1, {h2, h1, d, t,b, c}, Reals, 10,WorkingPrecision -> 10,Method -> "ZengDecision" -> True]
```

I want to find out all the solutions over the range given above for `h1`, `h2`, `b` and `c`. But here I just asked for 10 solutions it settles down the lower limit of `b` and `c`. But if I changed the range for `a` and `b` , from $(10^3,10^6)$ to $(10^2,10^6)$, I even lost these solutions, then it shows error. But still the new range covers the old range. So why it fails to give solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Your expression produces errors (`FindInstance::nsmet`, `ReplaceAll::reps`) with v12 on my Mac

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)
```

However, using exact numbers in the expression provides three solutions -- near the lower bounds for `b` and `c`

```
sol3 = {h2, h1, d, t, b, c} /. FindInstance[
   (h2^2 ((1 + d*Sin[t]^2)))/(16 π^2) b == 57/50 &&
    (h1*h2 (d (Sin[2 t])))/(2*16 π^2) c == 1/10 &&
    10^4 < b < 10^6 && 10^4 < c < 10^6 && 0 <= d <= 1 &&
    0 <= t <= π/2 && 1/100 < h2 < 1 && 1/10 < h1 < 1,
   {h2, h1, d, t, b, c}, Reals, 10,
   WorkingPrecision -> 10,
   Method -> "ZengDecision" -> True]
```

[image]

Extending the range of `b` and `c` produces 18 solutions but does not include the original 3 solutions. Again, the found solutions are near the lower bound for `b` and `c`. Presumably, the search starts near the lower bounds and is timing out before getting far from the lower bounds.

```
sol3rev = {h2, h1, d, t, b, c} /. FindInstance[
   (h2^2 ((1 + d*Sin[t]^2)))/(16 π^2) b == 57/50 &&
    (h1*h2 (d (Sin[2 t])))/(2*16 π^2) c == 1/10 &&
    10^2 < b < 10^6 && 10^2 < c < 10^6 && 0 <= d <= 1 &&
    0 <= t <= π/2 && 1/100 < h2 < 1 && 1/10 < h1 < 1,
   {h2, h1, d, t, b, c}, Reals, 20,
   WorkingPrecision -> 10,
   Method -> "ZengDecision" -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: That is the problem, it settles down at lower bound. Please any suggestions on how to scan for other solutions

Comment: @ImmySalam - break the intervals into small intervals and use `FindInstance` or `Reduce` on each of the smaller intervals. This is likely to take a long time for computation.